# Como actualizar un documento usando condicionales en mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Es posible, en una sola consulta, actualizar un documento según los datos que tenga en ese momento?

El caso: tengo un usuario que quiere guardar/remover los mensajes que le interesan. Si el mensaje le gusta, le da "guardar" y se agrega en el documento de dicho usuario. Si ya no le gusta, le da "remover" y se elimina en el documento de dicho usuario.

Los schemas:

```
const messageLiked = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  text: String,
  // otros campos
});

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String,
  email: String,
  messagesLiked: [messageLiked],
  // otros campos
});
```

Solución actual (ineficiente): A través de 2 consultas: una para validar la existencia del usuario y otra para actualizarlo.

```
const user = await User.findOne({
      email,
      messagesLiked: message,
    });

    let userUpdated;
    if (user) {
      userUpdated = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { email },
        { $pull: { messagesLiked: message } },
        { new: true }
      );
    } else {
      userUpdated = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { email },
        { $push: { messagesLiked: message } },
        { new: true }
      );
    }
```